# Aggregate the number of connections that each user MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I need to aggregate the number of connections that each user has
and to know how many mutual connections each pair of users have
Note that if user A is connected to user B then we have an entry (A,B) and (B,A)
from the following table user_table

[image]

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT USER1,COUNT(*) 
        FROM TABLE T1 GROUP BY 
      USER1 )
       UNION 
       (SELECT USER2,COUNT(*)
        FROM TABLE GROUP BY 
        USER2 WHERE USER2 NOT IN (SELECT 
         USER1 FROM TABLE GROUP BY 
          USER1 ) 
            )
```

> Can try this.